# How to loop over a RDD by index in Pyspark and replace column values?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to accompany the following I have done with a regular df in pandas with a RDD or Spark DF in pyspark.
I was trying to solve it with the foreach() function, but I have failed at all attempts. Has somebody got a neat solution for it?

```
for i in range(len(all_songs)):

   if all_songs['loudness'][i] >0:
        loudness = all_songs.loc[i, 'loudness']
        all_songs['loudness'][i] = loudness * -1
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if pure DataFrame API solution is valid for your case, but I would  achieve what you have described with the following code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

# Assume that `df` is your DataFrame
replaced_df = df.withColumn("loudness", when(col("loudness") > 0, col("loudness") * -1).otherwise(col("loudness")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Do you by chance know any Ressourcen for learning Pyspark?

Comment: Hmm, the one I typically recommend teaches Spark using Scala (https://rockthejvm.com/p/spark-essentials). For Python, I unfortunately haven't found any good source yet :/